# Question about Linear Conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have recently started learning linear algebra from Kostrikin-Manin's *Linear Algebra and Geometry*, and have run into the following problem:

> Let $S$ be some set and let $F(S)$ be the space of functions with values in the field $K$. Which of the following conditions are linear?
>
> 1. $f$ vanishes at a given point in S;
> 2. $f$ assumes the value $l$ at a given point in $S$;
> 3. $f$ vanishes at all points in a subset $S_0\subset S$;
> 4. $f$ vanishes at at least one point of a subset $S_0\subset S$.

I know that linear functions form a linear subspace of $F(S)$, so the way I interpret the question is that I need to verify the following: for $s,s_1,s_2\in S$, $a\in K$, we have (1) $f(s_1+s_2)=f(s_1)+f(s_2)$ and (2) $f(as)=af(s)$.

For 1, my solution is simple: for $s,t\in S$, we set $f(s)=0$, and let $f(t)=0\iff s=t$. This immediately fails the second property, as $f(as)\neq0$, but $af(s)=a\cdot0=0$. I can therefore conclude that the first condition is not linear.

However, I am struggling with the following parts. I believe that 2 is not sufficient to be a linear condition - I have no way of verifying either of the properties, or showing that they are false either. Similarly, for 3, I cannot apply a similar method as I did for 1, as I do not know if the elements of $S_0$ form a group under addition (i.e. if $s_1,s_2\in S_0\implies s_1+s_2\in S_0$), so I cannot verify the first property. Again for 4, I don't think I have enough information to show that it is a linear condition.

Am I missing out/misunderstanding something very badly, or are 2-4 all not linear conditions?

Answer (score 1):

1) $f$ vanishes at a given point in $S;$

This condition is linear because if $f(a)=0$ and $g(a)=0$, then $$(f+g)(a)=f(a)+g(a)=0$$ and $(\lambda f)(a)=(\lambda).(0)=0$

2)$f$ assumes the value l at a given point in S; This condition is not linear. Note that $1+1=2l$

3) $f$ vanishes at all points in a subset $S0⊂S;$

This condition is linear and the proof is similar to 1).

4) $f$ vanishes at at least one point of a subset $S0⊂S.$

This condition is not linear because different functions may vanish at different points.

Answer (score 0):

As you should know the set $F(S)$ is a linear space over the field $K$, the purpose of the problem is to determine if the subset defined by the proposed constraint has a structure of vector subspace of $F(S)$.

For instance, consider the first constraint (first item), then we have the following subset associated, given $x \in S$: 
$$A_1=\{f \in F(S) : f(x)=0\}, $$
the objective of the problem is to determine if $A_1$ is a vector subspace of $F(S)$.